# Why can't I connect an Access Point to this Network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp, wireless-access-point

A client hired me to install an Access Point to make his home network available via WiFi. The modem/router is a Motorola with the following specs (the list is based on observation as I don't have access to any manual or model number):

- A coaxial input for internet access
- A single 100 Mbps ethernet port
- No WiFi adapter

And the single computer that was connected to it had the following connection profile:

- IP (DHCP) `10.201.0.226`
- Subnet mask `255.255.0.0`
- Default gateway `10.201.0.1`

And it was able to correctly connect to the internet.

I'm not sure if the default gateway is the same as the ISR's address. The ISR had no way of configuration whatsoever…

But anyway, I proceeded to configure the Access Point as follows:

- IP address `10.201.0.2`
- Subnet mask `255.255.0.0`
- DHCP server off
- SSID `FOO`
- WPA2/PSK password `BAR`
- Operation mode Simple Access Point (No repeater, no bridge, no client, just the Access Point functionality)
- Phisically connected to the ISR via the only ethernet port that it had

And then I proceeded to connect the very same computer that was formerly connected via ethernet cable by using its internal WiFi NIC, and it worked pretty fine. Since it had DHCP still on, it auto-configured itself with the following profile:

- IP address (DHCP) `10.201.3.32`
- Subnet mask `255.255.0.0`
- Default gateway `10.201.0.1`

So I then *pinged* the following addresses:

- `10.201.3.32` (self) → success
- `10.201.0.2` (access point) → success
- `10.201.0.1` (default gateway) → success
- `8.8.8.8` (external DNS) → success

So you can say it was properly configured and able to access the internet. But then I tried to connect yet another host, with the following profile:

- IP address (static) `10.201.0.10`
- Subnet mask `255.255.0.0`
- Default gateway `10.201.0.1`

And proceeded to ping the following addresses:

- `10.201.0.10` (self) → success
- `10.201.0.2` (access point) → success
- `10.201.0.1` (default gateway) → No response (not "host not available", just no response).
- `8.8.8.8` (external DNS) → No response
- `10.201.3.32` (the other host) → success

It didn't work this time, weird. Then I disconnected and tried to let it configure the profile via DHCP but I noticed it got stuck with the same address I gave it when it was connected with a static address, i.e. the address didn't change. The strange part was that it was able to reach the other host that was connected to the same Access Point but not to the default gateway address.

What could be the problem? Is it a problem with the configuration on the Access Point? Does the ISR lack something (router, switch, etc.)? Would I need to install a switch in front of the ISR? What else does my topology lack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're actually using an Access Point (AP), that's likely the source of your problem. What you need is a Router, because the cable modem is providing only a single usable connection to the customer equipment. The cable modem may in fact only be allowing connections to the "outside world" from the first device to attempt such a connection.

With a router, the router will get that IP address and do NAT, so internal addresses will likely be in the default ranges of 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x.

Comment: Do you think this Access Point may let me configure at least a simple NAT setting? I wasn't able to fiddle with its features enough but do Access Points usually support a simple NAT configuration like the one @Overmind suggests?

Comment: If the product is actually an AP, then no - doing NAT is pretty much the definition of a router. There may be some options for separate subnets on sufficiently advanced APs, but I suspect if you were talking about US$1000+ equipment you'd have mentioned it. Having a router provides some other benefits, such as being able to have equipment (e.g. printers) not actually accessible to the world.

Comment: You can pick up a perfectly suitable router for dirt cheap. Plug the Motorola modem into the WAN port then plug the AP into one of the router's LAN ports, the desktop computer into another and then laptops/phones/wifi devices connect to the AP. You don't need a wifi enabled router because of the AP. E.g. http://docs.linn.co.uk/wiki/images/f/f8/RP614_both.jpg - this will do your NAT, DHCP and port forwarding etc.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the AP with the WAN setting of the initial computer (IP 10.201.0.226
Subnet mask 255.255.0.0, Default gateway 10.201.0.1 +  the original DNS). You can either put it statically or change the MAC address on the WAN side of the AP so it gets this IP automatically. Enable DHCP on LAN side. Let it give all clients a class like 192.168.1.1 (LAN side AP IP, and 192.168.1.2,3, etc for clients). Everything should then run fine.

Putting an IP for AP as 10.201.0.2 is not good at all. That IP may even be used in the ISP network.
No, additional switch will not help unless the AP has not enough LAN ports for you to connect every endpoint station that is not wireless.